# How to test for equality of two coefficients in regression?

Tags: r, linear-regression

How do I test for equality of two regression coefficients within the same model? I have the following code:

```
illegalscandal <- lm(PoliticalApproval ~ Ideology + Education + Age + Sex + FL_10_DO,
                    data = Qualtricsillegal)
```

`FL_10_DO` is a variable for two different types of political communication (denial, confession). Id like to test if there is equality between `T4` (confession) and `T3` (denial). Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi Alex, welcome to Stack Overflow. This website focuses on *specific* **programing** questions. It seems your question centers more on interpretation of statistical analysis. Therefore, your question may be more appropriate for [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Look at the linearHypothesis function. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37591550/testing-the-equality-of-multiple-coefficients-in-r

Comment: And please use reproduceable examples, including data.